# How would i take all of the data in a text file and put it into a text widget in tkinter + add a scroll bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How would i take all of the data in a text file and put it into a text widget in tkinter.

Also how would i get that text widget to have a scroll bar

I already have a program that outputs what i need to a .txt document but i am trying to find a good way to read and display that + have a scroll bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
file = open("filename.txt")
data = file.read()
file.close()

root = Tk()
widget = Text(root)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
widget.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=widget.yview)
widget.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
widget.insert(END, data)

root.mainloop()
```